# Removing from array values of checkboxes in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, checkbox

I have a checkboxes like this:

```
while($userRow=$resultForUsers->fetch_assoc()){
      $nameOfUser=$userRow['users_name'];
      $userId=$userRow['user_facebook_id'];
      $userFBPicture=$userRow['users_picture'];
      echo "
      <tr class='tr-data-users'>
      <td class='text-center'>
      <input type='checkbox' class='checkbox' onclick='if(this.checked){selo(this.value)}else{izbaci(this.value)}' value=$userId>
      </td>
```

So, for each user in my database I'm having one checkbox with value of his id. I need id's of all checked users(i.e checkboxes) in one array. I did it this way:

```
<input type='checkbox' class='checkbox' onclick='if(this.checked){put(this.value)}else{remove(this.value)}' value=$userId>
 var  niz={};
    var index=0;
        function put(o){
            niz[index++]=o;
            console.log(niz);
        }
```

So, `console.log` now displays id's of all checked checkboxes. What I want to do is if checkbox is unchecked then to remove that id(i.e chechbox value) from array. I tried it like this:

```
onclick='if(this.checked){put(this.value)}else{remove(this.value)}'
 var  niz={};
    var index=0;
        function put(o){
            niz[index++]=o;
            console.log(niz);
            remove(o,niz);
        }

        function remove(o,niz){
            if($.inArray(o,niz)){
                console.log('radim');
                var indexNiza= $.inArray(o,niz);
               niz= $.grep(niz,function(a,o){
                   return (a!=o);
               });
            }
        }
```

As you can see this `else` part should handle if checkbox is unchecked and remove that id from array, but it doesn't work. Would really appreciate help on this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that the code you have written is taking a very complex route for a simple job. You can see the following for a good example on how to obtain all of the values into their own arrays for the `checked` and `unchecked` states.

In the demonstration, I enumerate through the checked and unchecked checkboxes if the user changes the state of any checkbox, and store the checked values in an array named `cbChecked` and the unchecked values get stored in `cbUnchecked`

The key here is the selectors used:

#### Selector usage

Get all 'checked' objects

```
:checked
```

Get all 'unchecked' objects

```
:not(:checked)
```

---

### Demonstration

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  
  $("input[type='checkbox']").change(function() {
    var cbChecked = new Array();
    var cbUnchecked = new Array();
    $("input[type='checkbox']:checked").each(function() {
      cbChecked[cbChecked.length] = this.value;            
    });
    
    $("input[type='checkbox']:not(:checked)").each(function() {
      cbUnchecked[cbUnchecked.length] = this.value;            
    });
    
    $("p#cbChecked").html( cbChecked.join() );
    $("p#cbUnchecked").html( cbUnchecked.join() );
  
  });
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h2> The checkbox form</h2>
<form id="foo">
  <p>A : <input type="checkbox" id="a" value="a"></p>
  <p>B : <input type="checkbox" id="b" value="b"></p>
  <p>C : <input type="checkbox" id="c" value="c"></p>
  <p>D : <input type="checkbox" id="d" value="d"></p>
  <p>E : <input type="checkbox" id="e" value="e"></p>
  <p>F : <input type="checkbox" id="f" value="f"></p>
</form>

<h2>Checked Values</h2>
<p id="cbChecked"></p>

<h2>Unchecked Values</h2>
<p id="cbUnchecked"></p>
```

Comment: You did a pretty well job. :)